# I already render the list fetch API, but how to pass list data index to child component?

Tags: reactjs

How to pass fetch data to child component in react?

I do following..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableRow,
  Button,
  Icon
} from '@material-ui/core'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import api from '../../../../Services/Api'

class InvoiceTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      invoices: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { invoices } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="w-full flex flex-col">
          <Table className="min-w-xl" aria-labelledby="tableTitle">
           {invoices.map((invoice) => (
            <TableBody key={invoice.sales_invoice_id} onClick={() => console.log(invoice)}>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row" />
                <TableCell className="truncate" scope="row">
                  {invoice.sales_invoice_no}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
                    <Icon>touch_app</Icon>
                  </Button>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
            ))}
          </Table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(InvoiceTable)
```

I already render the list fetch API, but how to pass list data index to child component ?
can somebody help me how to solved it?

Comment: can you please explain which is your child component and what data you exactly want to pass to child?

Comment: class InvoiceDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() { 
        console.log(this.props)
        return ( 
            <div>
                {/* {invoice.status} */}
            </div>
         );
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You have `index` in `map`,

```
invoices.map((invoice,index) => (...))
```

**Update**

You want to navigate to another component, you can do using this

```
<TableBody key={index} onClick={() => this.props.history.push(/invoice-detail/${invoice.sales_invoice_id}/${invoice.sales_invoice_no})}>
```

You must have `Route` for this,

```
<Route path='/invoice-details/:invoice_id/:invoice_no' component={InvoiceDetail}>
```

In `InvoiceDetail` component, to get values passed as `params` you can do this,

```
console.log(this.props.match.params.invoice_id) // make sure `invoice_id` matches with your `Route`
console.log(this.props.match.params.invoice_no) // make sure `invoice_no` matches with your `Route`
```

Answer (score 0):

index is always the second parameter in map. You can pass the index to child component as a prop!

```
invoices.map((invoice,index) => {
return <Component index={index}/>

})
```